# Word for made-up scenario that stretches believability

Tags: single-word-requests

I believe the word starts with con-

It describes a made-up scenario that stretches the limits of believability and was clearly made up in order to further the individual's point.

Comment: [Misconstruction](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/misconstruction) comes somewhat close but not perfectly so

Comment: A conjecture? : Opinion or judgment based on inconclusive or incomplete evidence; guesswork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**contrived**" is often used as an adjective in the situation you describe.

to contrive - verb (used with object), contrived, contriving.

to plan with ingenuity; devise; invent:
The author contrived a clever plot.

Noun - contrivance; hope that gets you started;)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contrive

Comment: _Contrived_ was my first thought when reading the question :)

Answer (score 5):

You might be thinking of "confabulation" but the right word might be "bullshit."

Comment: *Bullshit* needs no explanation, but for a word like *confabulation*, it would be best to get in the habit of providing a definition.  That will strengthen your answer and maximize its usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

Confabulation?

> Noun - *confabulation* ‎(plural *confabulations*)

1. A casual conversation; a chat.
2. (psychology) A fabricated memory believed to be true.

Answer (score 1):

**concoction** (*noun*):

(Defn. 1.1) an elaborate story, especially a fabricated one

> '*her story is an improbable concoction*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 0):

A different description to you might be a *straw man* argument. "A weak or imaginary argument or opponent that is set up to be easily defeated"

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strawman

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are thinking of **construct**?

**construct** (*noun*):

(Defn. 1) An idea or theory containing various conceptual elements, typically one considered to be subjective and not based on empirical evidence

> '*history is largely an ideological construct*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)